# PowerShell print variable output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to  get a list of Active Directory users that have not logged in in X days, then write it to a text file. I'm having a problem with writing it to a text file. Here is what I have:

```
$date = Get-Date
$disable45 = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "distinguished_name" | ? {
    ($_.distinguishedname -notlike 'Disabled') -or
    ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "Service Accounts")
} | Where-Object {
    $_.LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
} | select SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,Enabled,distinguishedname) | Write-Host

Add-Content C:\users\user1\Desktop\disable.txt "$date`n`n$disable45`n`nThe End`n`n"
```

The variable works properly by itself. The `Add-Content` part appends correctly to the file. But the output from the `$disable45` variable is not in the file. There is just blank space or space with "|" symbols. I've tried using "{" and "[" and "(" around the disable variable, but I still cannot get it to write the output in the file.

Comment: Remove the `| write-host` from the variable assignment

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work. It won't let me insert a screen shot of what I get, but I just get blank space separated by three pipe lines.

Comment: Export it to csv file instead of text file. Remove Add-Content code & replace write-host with Export-CSV C:\Users\disable.csv

Comment: use filter instead of where-object and don't use "-properties *"........Ex: get-aduser -filter  "DistinguishedName -notlike 'Service Accounts'" -properties LastlogonDate | select SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,Enabled,distinguishedname | export-csv c:\disable.csv

Comment: The text file is because the next step I'll build into this is to move any account past the inactive time to a specific OU and I also want to write those actions to a file, creating my own log. I figured once I learned what is wrong with my current syntax, I would just reuse the correct syntax in my next steps.

Comment: I solved the problem removing the write host, addint the date to the text file first, then this:    foreach ($user in $disable45)
    {
    $UserD = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName
    Add-Content C:\users\user1\Desktop\disable.txt "$UserD`n"
    }

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem removing the write host, adding the date to the text file first, then this:
    foreach ($user in $disable45) { $UserD = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName Add-Content C:\users\user1\Desktop\disable.txt "$UserD`n" }